# why does my openpyxl load only pull one cell in worksheet

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have this `openpyxl` intent on reading rows in an XLSX document.

But for some reason it is only reading the value in cell `A1`, then finishing.

What am I missing?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

Dutch = load_workbook(filename='languages/READY-Language Translation-- August (SOS) Dutch_dut_Compared_Results.xlsx', read_only=True)
Dws = Dutch.get_sheet_by_name(name='Ouput')

for row in Dws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you load your workbook in read mode, and openpyxl is not reading the sheet as expected, say A1:A1, you can reset the max row and col with `ws.reset_dimensions()`.

[Documentaion here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html#worksheet-dimensions)

Example:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='languages/READY-Language Translation-- August (SOS) Dutch_dut_Compared_Results.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['Ouput']
ws.reset_dimensions()

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read-only mode depends to a large extent on the metadata provided by the file you're reading, particularly the "dimensions". You can check this by seeing what `ws.max_row` and `ws.max_col` are. If these are different to what you expect then the metadata in the file is incorrect. You can force openpyxl to recalculate these values with `ws.calculate_dimensions()` but this is inadvisable as it forces openpyxl to read the whole sheet. Better is simply to reset the underlying values so that openpyxl knows the worksheet is unsized.

Comment: Ok.  Assuming that I cannot change the excel file, is there another way? Or does recalculate turn into the only solution?